# Finding the probability of the average of a collection being greater than some number.

Tags: probability, data-analysis

Say that we have a list of `k` elements. How could we find the probability that a random collection of `n` (`n` < `k`) of the elements in that list would have an average value greater than some other value `m`.

Put as an example, given `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,9]` how could we find the probability that a random collection of 4 of those elements (such as `[4,2,6,9]` or `[9,2,1,9]`) would have an average less than 5.